# The continuity of $E[X \sin^2 (Xt)]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, continuity

Suppose $X$ is an integrable random variable.

$f(t) = E[X \sin^2 (Xt)]$ is also finite. ($t \in \mathbb{R}$)

And $f$ must be a continuous function of $t$, but I can't prove it using $\epsilon - \delta$. One reason is that $f$ is a integrated function, but anyway I'd like to ask you
for the (hint or sketch of) proof of this continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(t_n)_n$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$ having $t\in\mathbb R$ as limit.

Then it is enough to prove that $(f(t_n))_n$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$ with $f(t)$ as limit.

For this define random variables $Y,Y_n$ as $Y:=X\sin^2(Xt)$ and $Y_n:=X\sin^2(Xt_n)$.

Then evidently $Y_n\to Y$ a.s. and with application of [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) we can prove that $\mathbb EY_n$ converges to $\mathbb EY$.